# AngularFire authentication registration

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularfire

I'm trying to implement a registration for my angularFire firebase. I have all forms of login working including local and social solutions. But I'm kind of stuck on how to go about creating a registration for those who do not use social media sites. The simple login does work but I have to add the usernames and password myself. Has anybody had to deal with this or has anyone found a solution to AngularFire simple login registration. I'd really appreciate any help. To give you an idea of where I'm at this is the login controller.

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://<<myfirebase>>.firebaseio.com");
angularFireAuth.initialize(ref, {
scope: $scope, name: "user",
callback: function(err, user) {
  if (!err) {
      console.log("User :", user);
  } else {
      console.log("Error :", err);
  }
}
});
$scope.login = function() {
console.log("logging in");
var username = $scope.form.email;
var password = $scope.form.password;
angularFireAuth.login('password', {
    email: username,
    password: password,
    rememberMe: false
  });
};

$scope.loginTwitter = function() {
    console.log('loggin in via Twitter');
    angularFireAuth.login('twitter');
};

$scope.loginFacebook = function() {
    console.log('loggin in via Facebook');
    angularFireAuth.login('facebook');
};

$scope.loginGithub = function() {
    console.log('loggin in via Github');
    angularFireAuth.login('github');
};

$scope.logout = function() {
  angularFireAuth.logout();
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the angularFireAuth.createUser method to programmatically create a new user (in most cases based on user input on a signup form):

```js
function createNewUser(email, pw) {
  angularFireAuth.createUser(email, password, callback);
}
```

The callback will be called when the user has been created successfully (or there was an error). Usually, you'll want to bind this method to the submit button of a form.